# $n$ lamps around a circle, find all $n$ such that the lamps can all be turned off after some moves.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $n \ge 3$ lamps around a circle, some switched on, the rest off. Let each move consist of toggling $3$ consecutive lamps. Find all $n$ such that it is possible to switch all lamps off after using a number of moves.

I've conjectured that all $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ is impossible, while all other $n$ is possible through brute force. I'm trying to prove that for all $n$ not divisible by $3$ it is possible to execute a sequence of moves such that after the entire sequence, exactly one lamp has changed state, but I'm having some trouble. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Let $m_i$, $1 \le i \le n$ be the number of togglings of the three consecutive lamps $i, i + 1 \mod n, i + 2 \mod n$. We can limit $m_i$ to be equal to $0$ or $1$, since every other even or respectively odd number would give the same result.
Let $c_i$, $1 \le i \le n$ be $1$ if the lamp $i$ change state at the end of the sequence and $0$ otherwise. You want $c_1 = 1$ and $c_i = 0$, $2 \le i \le n$. We have: $c_1 = m_{n-1} + m_n + m_1 = 1 \pmod{2}, c_2 = \ldots$ Try to go on from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you can always turn off all the lamps if and only if $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$. Since this is a fun puzzle, I would prefer to give hints.

- If $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$, imagine dividing the lamps into three groups, red, green, and blue, by the repeating pattern $R, G, B, R, G, B,\dots$ Think about how the operation interacts with the lamps in each grouping, and find an invariant quantity.
- If $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$, note that by toggling the block $(i,i+1,i+2)$, and then $(i+1,i+2,i+3)$, then net effect is that only $i$ and $i+3$ are toggled. Using this, you can also toggle $(i,i+6)$ alone, and $(i,i+9)$ alone, and in general $(i,i+3k)$ alone for any $k$, where the indices wrap around mod $n$. Since $3$ and $n$ are coprime, this allows you to toggle $(i,i+j)$ for *any* $j$ (how?). With this power, you should be able to figure out how how to turn off all the lights.