# $3n$ Lightbulbs in a circle - proof with group theory that you cannot turn all off from any starting state

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

The description of the problem is the same as [$n$ lamps around a circle, find all $n$ such that the lamps can all be turned off after some moves.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070494/n-lamps-around-a-circle-find-all-n-such-that-the-lamps-can-all-be-turned-of). I will brief it shortly.

So there are $3n$ lightbulbs on the circle, if you toggle the $k$-th lightbulb, then both $k-1$ and $k+1$ (mod $3n$) will also be toggled.

And I am asking if there is any group theory--related proof that proves you cannot turn off all the bulbs, starting from only one of them powered on.

I know this is a well-explored puzzle but I still wonder if there is any solution using group theory, rather than proving by enumerating all the possibilities of the case.

I have examined the case $n=2$, such that there will be 4 groups of state that you cannot start from one group and end in another.

Comment: Does it have to be group theory? Induction should work, I guess

Comment: Here's a first observation: We can let the set of ordered lamp configurations be the set $X=\{0,1\}^n$, and there are $n$ different group actions of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ on $X$ corresponding to the $n$ different triple flipping locations. Then these induce an action of $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^{\times n}$ on $X$, hence a group homomorphism $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^{\times n}\to S_{2^n}$ to the symmetric group on $2^n$ generators. The question then asks for which $n$ is the image of this map a transitive subgroup of $S_{2^n}$.